# How to empty adjacent cell if edited cell is blank?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Apps Script code timestamps an adjacent cell based on the watchCols when a cell is edited.

What I need to do is remove the timestamp if the user removes a value. E.g. they put an X in column 2 in any row if they complete one of a list of tasks, but if they remove the X meaning they didn't finish the task, there should be no timestamp beside it.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    watchCols = [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17],
    offsetCol = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    ind = watchCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
    if (s.getName() !== "Sheet1" || ind === -1) return;
    e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind])
    .setValue(!e.value ? null : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "YYYY-MMM-dd hh:m:s a"))
}
```

This is the last attempt I made which doesn't seem to work:

```
    if(ISBLANK(e.range.columnStart) && ISBLANK(e.range.rowStart)) {
    e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind]).setValue("");
    } else {
    e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind]).setValue(!e.value ? null : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "YYYY-MMM-dd hh:m:s a"))
    }
```

Comment: Well this is interesting... Meta kindly helped me with another problem, and by using an installable trigger, the original code works without modification... it empties the timestamp column if the user removes an X or whatever value is in the cell.  I'm not sure why it works, but will figure out why.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871241/how-to-allow-onedit-function-to-affect-protected-cell-in-a-google-sheet

Comment: By the way, your second attempt was hopeless because ISBLANK is a spreadsheet function, not an Apps Script function. Spreadsheet functions are not available in Apps Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an undocumented behavior of the edit [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), which I'd consider a bug. It behaves differently for installable on-edit triggers and the simple onEdit trigger, with regard to a user clearing a cell.

1. Installable trigger: `e.oldValue` has the old value, `e.value` is undefined (the event object has no `value` property).
2. Simple trigger: `e.oldValue` has the old value, `e.value` **holds the object** `{"oldValue":"whatever it was"}`

This is why your conditional statement with `!e.value` behaves differently in two cases: undefined is falsy, but an object is truthy.